# Why does OpenCV matchShape() match "X" with "N"?

Tags: python, opencv

I am comparing the contours of letters and have several cases of unexpected results. The most confusing to me is how X and N are being identified as best matches.

In the images below, yellow represents the unknown shape and blue represents candidate shapes.  The white numbers are the result returned by `cv.matchShapes` using `CONTOURS_MATCH_I3`.  (I've tried the other matching methods and just get similar odd results but with a different set of letters.)

Below shows X matching N better than X

[image: Results searching for best match for X]

Below shows N matching X better than N

[image: Results searching for best match for N]

At the end of the post are the raw data and below is a chart of the the data.

[image]

I can't come up with a rotation, scale, or skew to show that this is an optical illusion.  I'm not suggesting there is an issue in matchShapes but rather an issue in my understanding of Hu moments.

I'd appreciate if someone would take a moment (pun intended) and explain how `cv.matchShapes` is producing these results.

--- edited ----

The images below are the result of using poly-filled shapes.  I am still baffled how these letters match better than the correct ones.

[image: E and the best matches]

[image]

---

```
target_letter   
33  23
32  24
30  24
28  26
28  30
29  31
29  32
31  34
31  35
33  37
33  38
36  41
36  42
38  44
38  47
35  50
35  51
33  53
33  54
30  57
30  58
28  60
28  61
27  62
27  67
29  69
34  69
38  65
38  64
40  62
40  61
42  59
42  58
46  54
47  54
49  56
49  57
51  59
51  60
53  62
53  63
56  66
56  67
58  69
63  69
65  67
65  60
63  58
63  57
60  54
60  53
58  51
58  50
55  47
55  44
57  42
57  41
61  37
61  36
64  33
64  32
65  31
65  25
64  24
62  24
61  23
60  24
58  24
55  27
55  28
52  31
52  32
50  34
50  35
47  38
45  36
45  35
41  31
41  30
40  29
40  28
38  26
38  25
37  24
35  24
34  23

candidateLetter  N
10  3
9   4
7   4
6   5
5   5
5   6
4   7
4   9
3   10
3   44
4   45
4   47
6   49
12  49
13  48
13  47
14  46
14  23
15  22
17  24
17  25
21  29
21  30
24  33
24  34
27  37
27  38
31  42
31  43
34  46
34  47
35  48
36  48
37  49
43  49
45  47
45  6
43  4
38  4
36  6
36  8
35  9
35  27
36  28
36  29
34  31
33  30
33  29
31  27
31  26
27  22
27  21
24  18
24  17
21  14
21  13
18  10
18  9
13  4
11  4


candidateLetter X
10  2
9   3
7   3
6   4
6   6
5   7
5   8
6   9
6   11
8   13
8   14
10  16
10  17
14  21
14  22
16  24
16  25
13  28
13  29
10  32
10  33
7   36
7   37
5   39
5   40
4   41
4   46
6   48
11  48
15  44
15  43
17  41
17  40
19  38
19  37
21  35
21  34
23  32
26  35
26  36
28  38
28  39
30  41
30  42
33  45
33  46
35  48
40  48
42  46
42  39
40  37
40  36
37  33
37  32
34  29
34  28
32  26
32  23
34  21
34  20
37  17
37  16
41  12
41  11
42  10
42  4
41  3
39  3
38  2
37  3
35  3
32  6
32  7
29  10
29  11
27  13
27  14
24  17
21  14
21  13
18  10
18  9
17  8
17  7
15  5
15  4
14  3
12  3
11  2
```

Comment: It matches Hu image moments. See https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#matchshapes. Try matching filled (white) shapes on the black background rather than the outlines. See if those results are better. Moments are computed by the positions of all non-black (usually white) pixels. With outlines, you do not have many non-black pixels.

Comment: See also https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_more_functions/py_contours_more_functions.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39160445/explain-numbers-from-opencv-matchshapes and https://www.learnopencv.com/shape-matching-using-hu-moments-c-python/

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I had already read through all the links you sent and I am aware of the Hu moment invariants used by matchShapes.  I have tried using poly-filled shapes, as well as the shape outlines, but the results are essentially the same.  See the additional images I just added to the post.